# Parsing function docstring in sphinx.autodoc format

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I have many functions in Python of the type:

```
def foobar(one, two):
    """
    My function.
    :param int one: My one argument.
    :param int two: My two argument.
    :rtype: Something nice.
    """
    return 100 + one + two
```

And I need to parse the docstring to have a dictionary something like:

```
{
    'sdesc'  : 'My function.',
    'params' : [('one', 'My one argument.'), ('two', 'My two argument.')],
    'rtype'  : 'Something nice.'
}
```

I can use `sphinx.util.docstrings.prepare_docstring` as follows:

```
>>> prepare_docstring(foobar.__doc__)
['My function.', ':param int one: My one argument.', ':param int two: My two argument.', ':rtype: Something nice.', '']
```

I could create my own parser, maybe using regex for params and rtype, and stuff.

But is there a better way to do it or a better approach? How `sphinx.ext.autodoc` does it? Any other advice on how to parse this kind of docstrings?

Comment: Since Sphinx is open-source, you can find the autodoc module [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/122bbbbd002e0b1c66145d81097b7a69c216e917/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py?at=default).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[openstack/rally](https://github.com/openstack/rally)'s [`parse_docstrings()` (permalink)](https://github.com/openstack/rally/blob/7153e0cbc5b0e6433313a3bc6051b2c0775d3804/rally/common/plugin/info.py#L63-L110)
 take a function's docstring in reStructuredText (reST) format as an input and returns 4 values-short_description, long_description, params and returns

For e.g. if the function and its docstring is

```
def sample(self, task, deployment=None):
    """Start benchmark task.

    Implement sample function's long description.

    :param task: Path to the input task file.
    :param deployment: UUID or name of the deployment

    :returns: NIL
    """
```

Then parse_docstrings() function will return-

```
{ "short_description" : "Start benchmark task.",
  "long_description" : "Implement sample function's long description.",
  "params": [ { "name" : "task", "doc": "Path to the unput task file" },
              { "name" : "deployment", "doc" :  "UUID or name of the deployment" } ]
  "returns" : "NIL"
}
```

You can modify the above function as per your needs.

Comment: Two years later but finally a great response. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the function referenced in this answer doesn't support alternate `param type` specification format: when param is specified like `:param str name: User's name` (instead of `:param name: User's name` `:type name: str`) then it will not notice such param. This does not happen with the regex used in another answer.

Comment: @MarSoft - I forked it to support types - https://github.com/SamuelMarks/doctrans/blob/37810ff/doctrans/info.py

Answer (score 3):

`pip install docstring-parser`

support both ReST-style and Google-style docstrings,

see https://github.com/rr-/docstring_parser for details

Comment: I had issues with this parser not support the ReST format properly. Maybe I'll open a PR? - It also definitely lacks ReST type support IIRC… keep an eye on https://github.com/SamuelMarks/doctrans/blob/37810ff/doctrans/info.py though, will see what else I'll add…

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

This question had two years without a response. See the accepted response for a better option.

---

OLD:

I ended up using regular expressions. The particular system used by Sphinx of nested *Nodes*, where each node type has to parse their children is not very useful for my purposes. If someone care, this is the regex I used:

```
param_regex = re.compile(
    '^:param (?P<type>\w+)? (?P<param>\w+): (?P<doc>.*)$'
)
```

Comment: The accepted answer seems robust, but I had trouble installing Rally.  This answer work and is easy to implement, imho.

Comment: @MikeyE - You don't need to install Rally, just take the one Python file out, `info.py`